# Get a single value from state-list in compose

Tags: list, android-jetpack-compose, state, android-viewmodel

In a compose viewmodel I have a state list of data. Using Lazy column to display the data works well but in order to display a single item from the list as Text I have to check if the list is empty. There must be a better way to get a single list value. Can someone direct me to what I am missing?

```
@Composable
fun TheData(vm: NewViewModel) {
    val data = vm.theData

    if (data.value.isNotEmpty()) {
        data.value[0].title?.let { Text(it) }
    }
LazyColumn() {
        items(data.value) { data ->
            data.title?.let {
                Text(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```